# Ajuda com app e atualização

Tags: android, app, atualização

Quero criar um *app* para exibir vídeos com opção de download, ordenados por categorias, mas queria saber como adicionar novos vídeos sem precisar atualizar o `.apk`, somente atualizar os links para download e títulos para os novos vídeos adicionados...

Comment: Acho que não tem jeito por dentro da `Google Play`, até existe `APK Expansion`, mas não é da forma como quer. Você terá que criar um `WebService` que sirva esses vídeos.

Comment: Tipo assim, os vídeos seriam hospedados em um servidor...
Teria como adicionar novos vídeos sem atualizar o apk?

Comment: Você poderia hospedar os vídeos em algum servidor e baixar os vídeos na memória interna do dispositivo (SD ou disco interno).

Comment: Ao invés de baixar seria melhor exibir os vídeos online, mas como atualizar os videos hospedados?

Comment: Essa parte é outra coisa, vai depender de como implementar.

Comment: Tem como dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira simples é utilizar um banco de dados SQLite para armazenar essa lista de vídeos. No caso, o aplicativo leria os dados dos videos do BD e os exibiria, assim você só precisaria atualizar o BD ao invés do aplicativo como um todo. [Aqui](http://www.mobiltec.com.br/blog/index.php/android-persistencia-de-dados-usando-sqlite/) você encontra um material sobre SQLite para Android. É a maneira mais simples que consigo imaginar.